# Jquery filter out the double class name with each function

Tags: jquery

Here is the example code

html

```
<div class="class-name-1"></div>
<div class="class-name-1"></div>

<div class="class-name-2"></div>
<div class="class-name-2"></div>

...

<div class="class-name-30"></div>
<div class="class-name-30"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('class^=class-name-').each(function() {
  console.log($(this));

  fn_myFunction();
});
```

This script will run sixty times `fn_myFunction()`, i would like to run `fn_myFunction()` only once for each `class^=class-name-`, that mean make above script run `fn_myFunction()` total thirty times.

Return first or last element is also ok.

And i would like to keep the jquery selector as `$('class^=class-name-')` if possible.

How can i do this with jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build an array of unique classes and then filter the elements accordingly using the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

In the example below, `$uniqueElements` is a jQuery object representing the filtered elements.

```js
var uniqueClasses = [];
var $uniqueElements = $('[class*=class-name-]').filter(function () {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').match(/class-name-\d+/)[0];
  return uniqueClasses.indexOf(classes) === -1 ? uniqueClasses.push(classes) : 0;
});

$uniqueElements.css('background-color', '#f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-class class-name-1 other-class">class-name-1</div>
<div class="first-class class-name-1 other-class">class-name-1</div>

<div class="class-name-2">class-name-2</div>
<div class="class-name-2">class-name-2</div>
```

Then you can iterate over each element in `$uniqueElements` and invoke your function:

```js
var uniqueClasses = [];
var $uniqueElements = $('[class*=class-name-]').filter(function () {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').match(/class-name-\d+/)[0];
  return uniqueClasses.indexOf(classes) === -1 ? uniqueClasses.push(classes) : 0;
});

$uniqueElements.each(fn_myFunction);

function fn_myFunction () {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-class class-name-1 other-class">class-name-1</div>
<div class="first-class class-name-1 other-class">class-name-1</div>

<div class="class-name-2">class-name-2</div>
<div class="class-name-2">class-name-2</div>
```

Comment: Its work, i would like to ask more info, hope you feel free to take a look :) when i have more than one class at the element, its seem not work, how can `classes` get the class that i need when more than one class at the element? Thanks :)

Comment: @aboutjquery Good point. Updated. You can use `.match(/class-name-\d+/)[0]` to match that specific class.

Answer (score 2):

`$('class^=class-name-')` not appear to be a valid jQuery selector ?

Try adding brackets around selector , using [next sibling](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) selector to match elements where the element has a sibgling having same `className` , which should return at most two elements; one `"class-name-1"` , one `"class-name-2"` , given `html` at Question

```js
$("[class^=class-name-]").each(function() {
  if ($("~ ." + this.className, this).length) {
    // some function here
    console.log(this)
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-name-1"></div>
<div class="class-name-1"></div>

<div class="class-name-2"></div>
<div class="class-name-2"></div>
```

Comment: good answer +1 ..and please update your snippet to make a live action like background instead of console.log

Comment: And what if the elements aren't direct siblings?

Comment: @JoshCrozier _"And what if the elements aren't direct siblings?"_ Did not address this possibility at `js` , or `html` ; used `html` at Question as template for stacksnippets . Would probably adjust approach at post  as minimally as possible to achieve same result , for example , use parent element of `this.className` with next sibling selector

Answer (score 0):

Try add a class mask in your divs.

Sample:

```html
<div class="class-name-1 mask"></div>
<div class="class-name-1 mask"></div>

<div class="class-name-2 mask"></div>
<div class="class-name-2 mask"></div>

...

<div class="class-name-30 mask"></div>
<div class="class-name-30 mask"></div>
```

Now, just make a JQuery to the new class:

```js
$('.mask').each(function() {
  console.log($(this));

  fn_myFunction();
});
```